# Clean cache command in Shell-script file

Tags: linux, shell-script

How could I solve this error?

From bash file I run the script to clean server cache.

```
`ssh -T root@${HLDB_SERVER} "bash -c 'free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free'"`
echo "Cache is cleaned!"
echo ""
```

I have got this error

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: Why we you running it in back ticks?

Comment: because I want to run on the remote server with ssh

Comment: Yes, I think I should remove it.